# Can’t claim my reward in Pokémon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

I can’t claim my reward. I checked my storage for both bag and Pokémon and there’s plenty of room.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot you posted, you haven't fully completed the challenge yet. In this case, you must

1. Power up Pokemon 10 times
2. **And** Battle another Trainer in the Great League
3. **And** Battle in a Raid

Once you have completed and redeemed each individual tasks within the challenge, only then can you redeem the challenge rewards.